# Vue <router-link> inside the child <router-view> component doesn't update the parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, nested-routes

I am using `<router-view>` for nested routing in my Vue application.
The child component has a link component, and when I click the link, it doesn't update the parent component, but only the child component.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

router.js

```
...
{
  path: 'companies/:id',
  component: () => import('.../companies/view/index'),
  children: [
    {
      path: 'info',
      component: () => import('.../companies/view/info'),
    },
    {
      path: 'address',
      component: () => import('.../companies/view/address'),
    }
  ]
...
```

I placed the `<router-view>` component in the index.vue file to show info and address components.

In the info.vue,

```
<router-link to="companies/11/address">address</router-link>
```

Comment: you should show the relevant parts of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue Routing - Reacting to Params Changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Should update the component on route param changes.